# Calculus and integration

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, self-learning

Hi I recently read one that the domain of an accumulation function is always an open interval this does not quite make sense to me for example why can't the domain be a closed interval some help would be appreciated as I've been confused for a while

Comment: Can you please state your definition of an accumulation function?

Comment: $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Comment: Thats not the definition of "accumulation function." $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ is a number !

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:I \to \mathbb R$ be a integrable function ,where $I$ is an interval in $ \mathbb R$,  then a function $F$ of the form

$$F(x) = \int_\xi^x f(t)dt$$

is called an accumulation function, where $\xi \in I$ and $x \in I$.

The interval $I$ has not to be open, $I$ can be an interval of any form $(a,b), (a, \infty), [a,b]$, ...... .